# Using JQuery to get and display Categories and Sub Categories - ALL AJAX

Tags: c#, .net, jquery

**Here is the scenario :: Setup**

I have a list of Categories, and within those categories i have sub categories, and wihtin those i would have sub sub categories, etc.  Follow?

> Ex:
>
> **Category Flow that Exists**
>
> Ex 1. Auto -> Parts -> Tires
>
> Ex 2. Auto -> Body -> Hood

Now

On the ui i would initally display **Auto** and on "click" i would like to show the sub categories wich would be "Parts" and "Body".

Now i can product that just fine, however what can i do to be able to product an additional sub sub categories?

> What I'm Using and What im Looking for

I am using C#.net with SQL Server Database.  Currently im using generic handlers to produce the desired text results.  However that is causing problems when i attempt to get sub sub categories.

I need someone to tell me the right way to do it using c#.NEt and JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need three combo boxes.

Add a jQuery change event handler to each combo box. When the combo box changes, use ajax to go back to your database and fetch the child entries for the item you selected.